# how to loop a video in html

Tags: html

how do i loop a video in html

using this code, can someone tell me what i need to add to make it loop

```
<embed src="man.mov" width="320" height="320"> </embed>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-media-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop attribute needs to be set to true. And attribute values have to be put into "".

```
<embed src="man.mov" width="320" height="320" loop="true"> </embed>
```

Comment: This page `https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video` claims that `loop="loop"` is the correct sytax.

Answer (score 3):

`< SRC="../graphics/sounds/helloo.wav" LOOP=TRUE HEIGHT=60 WIDTH=144>`

Comment: Or neater formatted: `<embed src="../graphics/sounds/helloo.wav" loop="true" height="60" width="144">` :)

Answer (score 2):

try HTML5 video tag it will provide you all facilities you can easily handle all operation on you video player

Answer (score 1):

You can use following to loop the video.

`<embed src="man.mov" width="320" height="320" loop=true> </embed>`

It is simple property loop, default is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop youtube videos by adding `&loop=1` to the end of the src url.